# grepping HPC jobs

Tags: awk, grep

let say, I have table in the imagewhich is basically "qstat" of HPC jobs:

[image]

I like to print out columns 2 and 6 which match NDS==1 and TSK==1
I am using command:

qstat -a |grep ' $4=="1" $5=="1" ' |awk '{print $2, $6}'

It shows no output with no error message. What I am missing?

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It makes it very difficult to test whether solutions actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing `grep` and `awk` slightly.

With `grep ' $4=="1" $5=="1" '`, `grep` would interpret `$4=="1" $5=="1"` as a regular expression.  This expression would try to match a `4` occuring after the end of the line (`$`), which can never happen.

Instead:

```
qstat -a | awk '$4 == "1" && $5 == "1" { print $2, $6 }'
```

If you want the header as well:

```
qstat -a | awk 'NR == 1 || ($4 == "1" && $5 == "1") { print $2, $6 }'
```

Comment: @Akand That would trigger the `print` statement for the header line as well (the first input line which has `NR` equal to 1), so that you get the column names. This is what I meant by "if you want the header as well".

Comment: @Akand If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).